# Which version of mysql do I need to be able to use clustering? 5.1.61 or 5.5....

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, high-availability

We have an application that will capture different images from users and make them into albums. we would like to think of going for high availability options as we observe the data is really growing faster and we cant be OK with down times.

All our MYSQL servers are versioned 5.1.61.

Now my question is shall these servers(5.1.61) support clustering or we need to upgrade these to 5.5..?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY

Comment: Which one is your question: 1) should I use mysql clustering for this application? 2) does mysql 5,1,61 support clustering?

Comment: does mysql 5.1.61 support clustering...? I mean the second one.

Comment: [Try the manual perhaps?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster.html). I would suggest you look at master - slave replication as opposed to clustering unless you have a competent DBA.

Comment: thank you for you advice nnichols. in the manual it is mentioned clustering will be given as a separate release but i coudnt see something that is about the version compatability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SchoonerSQL, a commercially-licensed full build of MySQL, is a high-availability database built exclusively on InnoDB.  We have altered it to maximize throughput, especially on SSDs or flash memory, but it is very fast and keeps data consistent between the Master and Slaves. SchoonerSQL is 100% compatible with MySQL so it is simple to move to SchoonerSQL or back again to Oracle's release if you ever decide to do that.

Comment: But all our tables are MYISAM tables jon. Anyways thanks for the info.